# How to add a sub heading inside an Antd table?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, antd

I want a table that has headings inside the table as given in the image below. I couldn't find a table like this in their official documentation and didn't find any luck with googling also. Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't think they have a built-in solution for this. But you can add the sub headings with this custom solution:

- Use the [JSX Style Api](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-jsx)
- The Column component takes a ['render'](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) prop where you can pass a custom react component which will replace that column.
- In that custom component you can add your custom Sub Heading for the columns you want.